# Can I grow first item of an odd number of items in a flexbox rather than last

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I have an odd number of items the last item grows to fill the space.

Can I have the first item be the one that grows, rather than the last?

Example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/winchendonsprings/pen/pEyWbE)

Code below:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try to style this using  child CSS selector

ul.flex-container:first-child{
   width:100%;
/* or some other styling that you need */ 
}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible when you are wrapping the `flexbox` items. But here is a workaround of sorts if that will do- use `wrap-reverse` instead :

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have in mind except in the wrong order. Lets say this is a blog, now the entries go in reverse order

Comment: You can write the html in reverse order to make it right. AFAIK this is the only way if you want it to behave responsively as it is doing now...

Answer (score 0):

This does what you need:

```
.flex-container {
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

This reverses the `flex-wrap` direction, which puts the stretched item first. Then `flex-direction` re-orders the items so that they are in their original order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this media

```
@media screen and(max-width: 800px){
  .flex-container .flex-item:first-child {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}
```